# Paste with condition and by group in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe including sample names, measurement modes and starting times of measurement. The measurements are continuous and each sample is sequentially measured using all the modes.

```
##example
df <- data.frame(sample= rep(c(1:10),each = 4,length.out=100),
                 mode =rep_len(c("A","B","C","D"),length.out = 100),
                 time= seq(strptime("2018-1-1 0:0:0","%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),by= dseconds(200),length.out=100))
```

For each sample I need to get an ID composed by the sample name and the starting time of mode "B".
I grouped it by sample using:

```
group <- function(x) cumsum(c(1, diff(x) != 0))
df$group <- group(df$sample)
```

then I tried to fill the new column `ID` using

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(ID = paste(df$sample,
                    as.character(substr(df$time, start = 12,stop=16)),sep="_"))
```

however this code doesn't work and in addition it would paste all the starting times and not the ones corrisponding to the mode "B".

Comment: After the `group_by`, step, don't use `df$sample`, just do `sample` as it will take all the elements of the column (breaks the group by operation) and similarly `time` instead of `df$time`

Comment: Also, I think `group_by` is not needed here based on the operation `df %>% mutate(ID = paste(sample, substr(time, start=12, stop = 16), sep="_"))`

Answer (score 1):

In your mutate command you do not need to reference your dataframe (df).  You only need to reference the column ID.  I believe this code will work for you.

```
 df%>%
  group_by(group)%>%
  mutate(ID = paste(sample,as.character(substr(time, start = 12,stop=16)),sep="_"))
```

Comment: Thank you! But how is possible to fill the column with only the combination between sample name and starting time of mode “B” for each group? Basically I need an unique ID for each group